# How to handle Exception properly from a method?

Tags: java, exception

Suppose, I have a method:

```
private void someMethod() {
    try {
        //Do something here
    }
    catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        System.out.println("error");
    }
}
```

Now, I want to use this method somewhere else:

```
private void newMethod() {
    someMethod();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exception didn't occur");  
}
```

Now, I want that if exception occurs in `someMethod()`, then `newMethod()` will not advance further, I mean, the `JOptionPane` message will not be shown in this case.

What will be the best way to do that? I have found a way by throwing another `NullPointerException` in catch block of `someMethod()` and then handling that from `newMethod()`. The code below demonstrates that:

```
private void someMethod() {
    try {
        //Do something here
    }
    catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        System.out.println("error");
        throw new NullPointerException("error");
    }
}

private void newMethod() {
    try {
        someMethod();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exception didn't occur");
    }
    catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        System.out.println("error");
    }           
}
```

But, by this method, I am facing some difficulties for other cases. I guess there are better ways to achieve that. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Rethrow the exception; throw a new exception; don't handle the original exception to big with; return a state value - which you use will depend on your ultimate goal

Comment: I mean, it depends. Is there any reason `someMethod` should be handling the exception? If so, then it should probably return a "state" value indicating the success of the operation.  If "newMethod" is depended on the outcome of "someMethod", then you should consider either allowing the exception to fall through (not handle in `someMethod`) or rethrowing it, it all depends.

Comment: Is this specifically about [tag:nullpointerexception] or are you asking about exceptions in general? It would be good to add original code, so we know why you want to handle the exception in method and then outside of method and why it is a problem in some cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to handle the exception inside `someMethod`. Instead you can declare the exception in this method's `throws` clause (if it is a checked exception) and let `newMethod` handle it.

```
private void someMethod() throws SomeCheckedException {
   //Do something here
}
```

In case of NullPointerException, you don't need to do above, as it is an unchecked exception. Don't catch it inside `someMethod`, instead have try-catch inside `newMethod`.

Comment: But I had to catch the exception because, if exception occurs, then I had some actions.

Comment: Ok if you want to perform some action inside `someMethod` as well, in that case rethrowing like you did is the only option.

Comment: @RakibulIslam *"if exception occurs, then I had some actions"* then rethrow the exception or throw a new one, which is better describes what went wrong or return a "state" of the operation

Comment: @curlyBraces Don't rethrow *a new* exception; rethrow *the same one* (or wrap it as the cause).

Comment: @chrylis yes that's indeed better

Answer (score 1):

It is good practice if your function intend to throw exception make it part of function declaration. So recommendation is to change `someMethod()`  to `private void someMethod() throws <exception Name>`.

Depends on your requirement you can handle the exception in same method and throw another exception, or re throw same exception and handle it in another function.

In case you are re-throwing the same exception syntax is as follows:

```
private void someMethod() throws WhateverException  {
    try {
        //Do something here
    }
    catch (WhateverException e) {
        throw e;
    }

}
```